# POS Pattern Filter?

Tags: nlp, nltk

I'm writing some code that iterates a set of POS tags (generated by pos_tag in NLTK) to search for POS patterns. Matching sets of POS tags are stored in a list for later processing. Surely a regex-style pattern filter already exists for a task like this, but a couple of initial google searches didn't give me anything.

Are there any code snippets out there that can do my POS pattern filtering for me?

Thanks,
Dave

EDIT: Complete solution (using RegexParser, and where messages is any string)

```
text = nltk.word_tokenize(message)
tags = nltk.pos_tag(text)
grammar = r"""
    RULE_1: {<JJ>+<NNP>*<NN>*}
    """
chunker = nltk.RegexpParser(grammar)
chunked = chunker.parse(tags)
def filter(tree):
    return (tree.node == "RULE_1")
for s in chunked.subtrees(filter):
    print s
```

Check out http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/book/ch07.html and http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html for more on creating the rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`RegexpChunkParser`](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.chunk.regexp.RegexpChunkParser-class.html).

Comment: More recent links that are probably useful for someone else: [NLTK book - CH7 - Chunking](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch07.html) and [NLTK HowTo - on Chunking](http://www.nltk.org/howto/chunk.html).